# Swift - How do I save images into an array and access them?

Tags: ios, arrays, database, swift

I have a map that allows me to add pins (annotations) to it. When I click on a pin, the app goes to another view controller and shows images downloaded from online. I "save" these images to an array but later I cannot access them. For example, when I tap "Back" to go to the previous view controller and tap on the same pin from before, instead of showing the images I originally downloaded and saved, new images are downloaded from online. Essentially, the images in the array are replaced. How can I save the images and retrieve them? Sorry for long amounts of code, I shortened as much as I could.

This is my class for the images:

```
class Image {

    var image: UIImage

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

This is my class for the pins. Notice, an array of type Image from the Image class is in here:

```
class Pin: Hashable {

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return "\(latitude.hashValue),\(longitude.hashValue)".hashValue
        }
    }

    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    var images = Array<Image>()

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
    {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}

// must be declared in the global scope! and not just in the class scope
func ==(lhs: Pin, rhs: Pin) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

I add pins to a Set like so (no duplicates of pins allowed). Also, the selected pin is sent to the secondViewController:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var pins = Set<Pin>()

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
 // Add pin to set
            let selectedCoordinatePoint = Pin(latitude: latFromPin, longitude: lonFromPin)
            var select = "\(latFromPin.hashValue),\(lonFromPin.hashValue)".hashValue
            pins.insert(selectedCoordinatePoint)

        //Goto to next view controller and show data depending on the pin selected
        for pin in pins {
            if pin.hashValue == select.hashValue {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CollectionViewControllerID") as! CollectionViewController

                    secondViewController.pin = pin

                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I download images from online and append to an array on this secondViewController (I shortened the code here):

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var pin: Pin!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


                if let photosArray = photosDictionary["photo"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    // println("photosArray  =  \(photosArray )")

                    var count = 0
                    for photo in photosArray {
                        // 6 - Grab 21 random images
                        if count <= 20 {
                            // Grabs 1 image
                            let randomPhotoIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(photosArray.count)))
                            let photoDictionary = photosArray[randomPhotoIndex] as [String:AnyObject]

                            // 7 - Get the image url
                            let imageUrlString = photoDictionary["url_m"] as? String
                            let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageUrlString!)

                            // 8 - If an image exists at the url, append to array
                            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL!)
                            let finalImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                            var image = Image(image: finalImage!)
                            self.pin.images.append(image)
                            count += 1

                            println(self.pin.images.count)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not I understand what your asking exactly...you are making network calls to populate your image array.  If you just want to pass the image array from VC to VC, you can use prepareForSegue to pass the value.

If you want to pull these down and then store them locally you need to read up on persistence.  For example you can use something like Core Data, Parse, Realm...I personally use Parse because of it's ease.  This is a good tutorial along the lines of what you're doing I think.  It uses Parse to store the image data: http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/

Comment: I updated my code to show the class names for each VC.  I'm storing pins in an array if the pin is selected. Once the pin is selected, it goes to the next view controller (CollectionViewController) and makes a network call. I store the images in an array with 'self.pin.images.append(image)'. If I go back to MapViewController and click the same pin, the images are replaced with another network call. I don't want this to happen; instead I want the original images. I am planning on adding Core Data in the future. Can this work simply while the iPhone is running and no Core Data?

Comment: Well, your first step is per my answer, needing to persist data.  If you go through the tutorial  I posted and build the sample app you will have a good understanding of how to do that.  Essentially you have no save function in your code right now, just network calls.  Once you understand that, then in your first view controller you can use an if or switch statement to check if there's already a value saved for that pin, if so display the saved data, if not, make the network call.

Comment: Ok, I will go through the tutorial and hopefully I can use it to solve this issue. I thought that appending to an array would "save" the data (not for long term storage like when the app is completely shut off, but at least enough to be able to switch between view controllers while the app is running).

Comment: No each VC is a local state, in other words if you create a variable in one VC you won't have access to it in another VC.  This is why it's either necessary to use prepareForSegue to pass from one to the other, or in your case, it sounds like you want to save it offline.  You could also use a Singleton for this, but long term given your app, I think it would be best to learn how to implement data persistence now, rather than having to refactor later.